# What is the proper way to deal with two datasets when .dropna() leaves them different sizes?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, dataset, na

I am testing out machine learning techniques by first using a model dataset and then a test dataset (csv files). However, using df.dropna(inplace=True) leaves them different sizes (model is 48470 and test is 48571). This causes multiple problems throughout my code.

So for example, while this works:

```
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

#Model fit to data
linear.fit(xmodel,ymodel.values.ravel())

#Prediction made by model
pred_linear = linear.predict(xtest)
## Compute RMSE
linear_rmse = mean_squared_error(ytest,pred_logit)
print("Linear regression RMSE is ",linear_rmse)
#Linear regression RMSE is  0.07557238168273192
```

On the other hand, I am having trouble plotting all the results:

```
x1=np.linspace(0,1,48571)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x1, yt, 'o', label="Data")
#ax.plot(x1, y_true, 'b-', label="True")
ax.plot(np.hstack((x1, xmodel)), np.hstack((ym, yt)), 'r', label="OLS prediction")
ax.legend(loc="best");
```

returns

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-29b0a94ea028> in <module>
     24 ax.plot(x1, yt, 'o', label="Data")
     25 #ax.plot(x1, y_true, 'b-', label="True")
---> 26 ax.plot(np.hstack((x1, xmodel)), np.hstack((ym, yt)), 'r', label="OLS prediction")
     27 ax.legend(loc="best");

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    284     # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    285     if arrs and arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 286         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    287     else:
    288         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Likewise (I believe it is a related problem, although if it isn't my apologies)

```
reg_model = sm.OLS(endog=ymodel, exog=xmodel)
reg_test = sm.OLS(endog=ytest, exog=xtest)
reg_model.fit()
reg_test.fit()
pred_regmodel=reg_model.predict(xtest)
pred_regtest=reg_test.predict(xtest) #Transpose sorta solved this, but takes forever   #xtest.iloc[9,:].values) technically solved shape problem, but gave false answer
regmodel_rmse = mean_squared_error(ytest,pred_regmodel)
print("OLS RMSE is ",regmodel_rmse)
```

Returns a similar mismatched dim error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-135-3ab9b9511c74> in <module>
      3 reg_model.fit()
      4 reg_test.fit()
----> 5 pred_regmodel=reg_model.predict(xtest)
      6 pred_regtest=reg_test.predict(xtest) #Transpose sorta solved this, but takes forever   #xtest.iloc[9,:].values) technically solved shape problem, but gave false answer
      7 regmodel_rmse = mean_squared_error(ytest,pred_regmodel)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py in predict(self, params, exog)
    343             exog = self.exog
    344 
--> 345         return np.dot(exog, params)
    346 
    347     def get_distribution(self, params, scale, exog=None, dist_class=None):

ValueError: shapes (48470,9) and (48571,9) not aligned: 9 (dim 1) != 48571 (dim 0)
```

I would like to form my graph to look like In[7] of [this statsmodels example](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html). As for the second example, my goal is to take my sm.OLS method train with either model data or test data, compare to the ytest df so that I can find MSRE ranges to compare with the logit/lasso/SVC/etc methods I've used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nessissity for the train and test dataset to be balanced. You only need the same number of features/columns as input. Your first eror is because of `x1` and `x_model` are different sizes, and `np.hstack` cannot stack different sizes

The second error, I feel x_test has got transposed. Try `x_test.T()`?